# How to perform two $pulls in a single query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is a an example document I have.

Users

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "users": [2,3,4,5],
    "scenarios": [11,22,44,55]
}
```

I'd like remove the elements 2 from users and 11 44 55 from scenarios. I was attemping to perform two $pull in a single update but I can't seem to get it to work with the following.

```
Users.update(
    { _id: 1},  
    {$pull: { users: 2 }, 
    {scenarios : '11 44 55' }, 
    function(err,numberaffected){}
);
```

Any help with the following query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `pullAll`

```
Users.update(
    { "_id": 1 },
    { "$pullAll": {"users": [2], "scenarios": [ 11, 44, 55 ]} }
    ,
    function(err, numAffected) {
    }
);
```

Like that, should do it.